# Creating an application for facebook that could gather data on page views by others

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to pull the information on someone viewing someone else's profile? Would that app be leagal on Facebook? There are lot of "fake" apps like that exist now on Facebook. But can that be done really?

Answer (score 2):

In short answer, No. Long answer, if Facebook allowed apps to collect such info it would a mess.